# data.table: assign to columns by column name matching

Tags: r, data.table

Say I have a datatable

```
> dt = data.table(Faaa = c(1,2,NA), Fbbb = c(2,NA,3), date = as.IDate(c("2010-01-01", "2010-01-02", NA)))
> dt
   Faaa Fbbb       date
1:    1    2 2010-01-01
2:    2   NA 2010-01-02
3:   NA    3       <NA>
```

Suppose there are lots of columns with name beginning with F. I want, for each column whose name begins with F, to impute the NA's with column mean, but not for the date (and any other) column.

For this question, the F-columns are next to each other, so I can access by index, just wonder if there is a clever way so that I don't need to hardcode column index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grep` and `na.aggregate` from `zoo` for this:

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

dt <- data.table(Faaa = c(1,2,NA), Fbbb = c(2,NA,3), date = as.IDate(c("2010-01-01", "2010-01-02", NA)))

cols = grep("^F", names(dt), value = TRUE)
dt[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, na.aggregate),.SDcols = cols]
```

Which result in:

```
   Faaa Fbbb       date
1:  1.0  2.0 2010-01-01
2:  2.0  2.5 2010-01-02
3:  1.5  3.0       <NA>
```

Comment: @akrun I would like to do it simpler and using just one line. 

With dplyr it would be: dt %>% mutate(across(contains("^F"),na.aggregate)) 

Why this doesn`t work? dt[, (names(.SD)) := lapply(.SD, na.aggregate), .SDcols = patterns("^F")]

How should we write it?